# Wrap java program's stdin/stdout

Tags: java, python, minecraft

I am writing a server management tool for the popular game minecraft.

This game and its server applications are written in java. The server is just a jar started from the terminal which accepts input from stdin as commands and outputs to stdout. (something among the lines of java -jar server.jar)

Now what I'm trying to do is create some kind of wrapper around these java processes (atm in python, i could go with java aswell) and create an API for managing them (send commands, restart, check if the process is still running, ...). I need this API so I can create a web front-end for the whole thing. One physical server will be running multiple instances of these java processes (multiple game servers) so I'd like to not have too much overhead here.

I've tried using python's subprocess but this blocks until the program finishes and then outputs the stdout contents, but I need it to return live. I also came across Pexpect (http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) but that appears to be more of a automated testing toolkit.

Comment: Doesn't RCON let you issue remote server commands already? Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @JonK That might be true, I'll have to look into that, thanks. But that still doesn't fully cover my problem. I want to dynamically create new server instances trough the web interface. This also means I need to start new processes on the server side, which RCON doesn't allow me.

Comment: You're correct on that last bit. As I understand it RCON just connects to a running server instance and interacts with it. Using it should at least take away some of the work you need to do though.

Comment: A Java program can run several subprocesses concurrently, using java.lang.Process in multiple threads, and you can redirect stdin, stdout and stderr of the subprocesses. Altogether, not a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your sever start command or script")
```

to get an instance of Process.

With the instance you can receive stdout of server by using

```
InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()),
```

and send bytes to it's stdin with

```
process.getOutputStream().write("your commannd\n".getBytes());
```

Remember to flush the ostream to execute the command!